# get a data type from a run-time given argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a type-generating function**ality** (need not to be a real function) that return a type from a run-time given parameter. For example,`get_me_type('d')` gives me `int` type. The following is my try and fail.

```
template<uint8_t N>
struct MagicType {};

template<>
struct MagicType<'d'> {
    using type = int;
};
```

Then I can declare type from a const char specilization.

```
   const char c = 'd';                   
   MagicType<c>::type y = 100;
```

Which looks fine. However, I cannot let `MagicType` receive an run-time argument. This makes MagicType useless to me.

```
// Error: complains about `t` is not a const expression. 
auto magic_helper(const uint8_t t, uint8_t* p) -> MagicType<t>::type {
    return *(MagicType<t>::type *)p;
}
```

**Question:** How can I generate data type from run-time argument?

Comment: You can't declare variables during run-time.  You can simulate this by using some sort of container and adding and removing objects from it during run-time.

Comment: In C++, types don't exist at runtime (except for RTTI, which will not work for non-class types). You might be able to use boost::any with a switch statement.